# Branch and Bound running time and golden ratio

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, optimization, branch-and-bound

This is a follow up question to [When does Branch and Bound exactly stop giving solutions for the bin packing problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56307/when-does-branch-and-bound-exactly-stop-giving-solutions-for-the-bin-packing-pro)

After testing many instances I found out that when **r = V / Vtotal** **<=** ***ϕ*** ([Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio)) the algorithm takes a lot of time to printout the result.

When the ratio **r** is so close to ***ϕ*** , I noticed that : **V / Vtotal = (V + Vtotal) / V**    (which represents the geometric relationship of the two quantities **V** and **Vtotal** in the Golden Ratio).

However, few of the instances having a ratio **r** **>** ***ϕ*** can take too long to print the results too.

So can this problem be related to ***ϕ*** or not?

PS: I got the idea of comparing it to ***ϕ*** after checking this answer [Lower bound on running time for solving 3-SAT if P = NP](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/lower-bound-on-running-time-for-solving-3-sat-if-p-np/19759#19759)

Comment: I guess there is no difference between $\phi$ or $\phi \pm \epsilon$.

Comment: @Raphael you are right (ps: I edited my question and added another information I noticed when testing)